# Array.set expects Array.Array Char but getting Maybe (Array.Array Char)

Tags: elm

not sure what the issue really is here.  I am new to Elm so be easy.

```
board = [ [ 'P', 'P', ' ' ], [ ' ', ' ', ' ' ], [ ' ', ' ', ' ' ] ]

move = nextBestMove board


nextBestMove : List (List Char) -> Int
nextBestMove gameNode =
    let
        node =
            map fromList gameNode

        -- node is now List (Array.Array Char)

        currentBoard =
            fromList node

        -- currentBoard is now Array.Array (Array.Array Char)

        row1 =
            get 0 currentBoard

        -- row1 is now Maybe.Maybe (Array.Array Char)

        -- now I want to place an X for the empty value in [ 'P', 'P', ' ' ]
        row1NextState =
            set 2 'X' row1

... rest of code
```

The **type mismatch error** I get is:

```
The 3rd argument to function `set` is causing a mismatch.

22|             set 2 'X' row1
                          ^^^^
Function `set` is expecting the 3rd argument to be:

    Array.Array Char

But it is:

    Maybe (Array.Array Char)
```

I don't understand why cause I figured now that I have a 2-dimensional array, that it should be good to go.  What I'm trying to do is to get a pointer to the first row in my game board.  So I want to get at [0][0] essentially so I can then update empty spot in row `[ 'P', 'P', ' ' ]`

Comment: Are you trying to set the empty spot in the row to X? So `[ 'P', 'P', ' X' ]`

Comment: yes..that's exactly what I'm trying to do.  I just don't get why there's Maybe involved here.. and why it's erroring on me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noted, the [get](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/1.0.0/Array#get) function spits out a `Maybe` type. That means we need to convert the `Maybe` type to an `Array` type to use it in `set`. We could use a function like [withDefault](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/1.0.0/Maybe#Maybe) here.

```
    row1NextState =
        set 2 'X' (withDefault (Array.initialize 3 (always ‘X’)) row1)
```

This makes elm use `[ 'X', 'X', 'X' ]` in case `row1` is `Nothing`.

Comment: tried your lines out, but get Function `set` is expecting 3 arguments, but was given 4.

21|             set 2 'X' withDefault ([ 'X', 'X', 'X' ] row1)

Comment: That should be 3 arguments... how about `set 2 'X' (withDefault [ 'X', 'X', 'X' ] row1)`

Comment: better but then I get 21|                        withDefault [ 'X', 'X', 'X' ] row1)
                                                         ^^^^
Function `withDefault` is expecting the 2nd argument to be:

    Maybe (List Char)

But it is:

    Maybe (Array.Array Char)

Comment: also curious why () is needed around the third param to set...again new to elm

Comment: tried this but no luck: `set 2 'X' (withDefault fromList [ 'X', 'X', 'X' ] row1)`.   
 Got the error 21|                        withDefault fromList [ 'X', 'X', 'X' ] row1)
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Function `withDefault` is expecting the 2nd argument to be:

    Maybe (List a -> Array.Array a)

But it is:

    List Char............About to go get some Advil....isn't the problem that `[ 'X', 'X', 'X' ]` is a list and we're trying to make that a default for an array since row1 is an array not a list?

Comment: The reason we need `()` around the third parameter is so `set` knows its one parameter. Otherwise it thinks `withDefault` is the parameter, when we really want the result of the whole function. Try: `set 2 'X' (withDefault (Array.initialize 3 (always ‘X’)) row1)`

Comment: Yes, the problem is that [ 'X', 'X', 'X' ] is a list, not an array. So we need to initialize an array first :)

Comment: your last suggested worked!  can you update your answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Me too I didn't know about `fromList`. I don't know off the top of my head but experiment with: `set 2 'X' (withDefault (fromList [ 'X', 'X', 'X' ]) row1)` or something like that. It looks much simpler.